# How can we send message to the android device from a browser of PC (both connected with same network)

Tags: android, networking

The main requirement which need to got is

Suppose I have a PC and have an Android Device. Now if my android app is open in my android device and i hit the url http://192.0.0.1?save=111 on browser of PC and when i hit i can get the value 111 in My App . 
Where 192.0.0.1 is IP address of android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you to be able to link a url to your app you will first need a small **http server embedded on your app**. [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) can easily be embedded. [Here](https://github.com/lopspower/AndroidWebServer) you can find an android app example.

Comment: Is it required to run the command in PC ? PC and device needs to be in same network ?

Comment: @Avinashtiwari actually, if you are using an embedded web server then you don't have to be in the same network and you don't need to send any adb command.  You can access directly using the http://device_ip:port. I have used a similar strategy to deploy a tiny REST api to an android server. If you need two way communication then better use sockets.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I need only one way communication that is sending update from PC to mobile device , I am checking your references right now

Comment: @Avinashtiwari then  the nanohttpd web server will be the easiest way https://github.com/lopspower/AndroidWebServer

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is to use Messaging protocols for that, for android you can use MQTT
Your browser will be accessing the MQTT sever, your android device will be running an MQTT client
Once all above is complete, you can send messages from your browser and your android device will receive the message almost instantaneously.
Read more about about MQTT here http://mqtt.org/

Comment: Url will be same if we use MQTT ? means the base url will be http://IPaddress?save=111 ?

Comment: Yes , the url can be same. You can encapsulate the functionality of sending notification messages behind an endpoint that is accessed via your preferred url.